# Toxicity problems with using propane gas to pressurize water

Tags: plumbing, water-pressure, health-and-safety, propane

I am working on a system to automatically maintain a safe tap water supply for a building in the case of a contaminated external water supply or in the case of loss of external water pressure, requiring interaction with the system only after the fact if one of those things occurs. One of the components of this system is a set of water tanks, which I will pressurize with nitrogen before filling part-way. This will allow the tank to maintain water pressure as the water is used up, even after the supply is cut off.

In order to test this concept, I am considering building a prototype that will use more readily available propane gas to in place of the nitrogen. I did consider using carbon dioxide, however that would end up carbonating the water, which is not what I am trying to do. Standard compressed air is unsuitable for the same reason.

I have already determined that the dissolved propane delivered through the water supply would not be enough to pose any sort of fire hazard under the conditions with which I intend to test the prototype. The maximum possible delivery from a 2 GPM faucet would be less than 5×10^-4 gallons of gas per minute, not even enough to require direct ventilation, at least not on account of averting an explosion hazard.

However, I am not sure whether the water delivered by such a prototype would be safe to drink. While the propane, ethane, ethyne, and isobutane in the propane are all nontoxic, propane gas also has ethyl mercaptan added to help detect leaks, and that is toxic at high enough concentrations. While there are techniques that could be used to remove it, I would rather keep it, as it serves a valuable purpose in helping detect leaks. I have been able to find exposure limits for it, at 0.5 ppm, but I have been unable to find information about the toxicity when ingested.

Where could I find limits for ingestion of ethyl mercaptan? Are there any other major hazards **that I did not already mention** that I need to consider before attempting to construct this prototype? Are there any other inexpensive types of gas that could be used to provide the needed pressure?

Comment: Nitrogen is readily available, cheap, nonflammable... I honestly can't see any reason you'd want to use propane instead, especially given that this is your eventual goal. Any welding-gas supplier can rent you a large tank and regulator and sell you the N2 inside it, or you can buy a smaller tank and regulator and have them fill it; assuming that you're gong to be experimenting for a while the latter may be a cheaper way to go.  In fact, some winemaking supply houses have nitrogen tanks and suitable regulators; if you've got one near you it might be a good idea to ask them about prices/sources.

Comment: Really good simulation of Natural Gas leakage into the water table during failed fracking. You get fire water and not in a good way.

Comment: Please provide more details about why you think compressed air is unsuitable.

Comment: @FiascoLabs Link? Plus, fracking is very different, as the pressures involved are hundreds of times higher than those in tap water.

Comment: @PhilipNgai CO2 reacts with water under pressure to form carbonic acid, which could corrode the metal interior of the tank. Compressed air has a large enough CO2 component that this could be a problem if I used compressed ait.

Comment: @FiascoLabs The solubility of a gas is (at reasonable pressures) roughly proportional to the pressure. At 1 atm, propane has a solubility of around 50 mg/L, so at the 2.5 atm (absolute) needed to get about 30 psi (relative) on the tap, the solubility would be 125 mg/L. Even if we assume that all of that gas comes out of solution immediately as it exits the tap, that comes out to less than a gram per minute. Propane has a density of 495 kg/m^3 at 1 atm, so that equates to about 6.7x10^-9 cfm.

Comment: @FiascoLabs (Continuing) (I mistyped, it is actually 6.7x10^-5 cfm, not 6.7x10^-9.) The LEL of propane is 2.1% by volume, so that means the minimum ventilation required to keep the concentration below that is only 0.0032 cfm, in contrast to the minimum long term _survivable_ ventilation rate of 12 cfm.

Comment: Don't forget that water has dissolved oxygen (I've seen dissolved air bubble out of the water after municipal pipe maintenance). I don't know the actual math, but you could find that you've ended up making a bomb if enough oxygen is liberated from the water in the tank to create an explosive mix of propane/oxygen, you're one spark away from a huge explosion. Nitrogen is not hard to find - every welding supply house will carry it, it might not be "food grade", but neither is propane.

Comment: Nobody has mentioned the obvious - buy a captive-air (bladder) pressure tank (accumulator) and be done with it. If you pressurize water with nitrogen without a bag/bladder/diaphragm, you're going to discover that nitrogen does dissolve in water. This is a very evolved technology where you are stunningly unlikely to invent something better than what already exists, and certain to spend more money "re-inventing" it than it would cost to buy.

Comment: If I could do more than +1 on ecnerwal's comment, I would.  Bladder tank is the way to go.  Look at reverse osmosis filter systems for examples.

Comment: @Ecnerwal That sounds like a much better idea. I would accept that if you wrote it up as an answer.

Comment: @Johnny Thanks for that reminder. I did the math, and since oxygen is twice as soluble in water as nitrogen, and far more soluble than propane, the the tank would be infiltrated by much more oxygen than one might expect, which could in fact accumulate over time and cause an explosion. I'd upvote that as an answer.

Comment: @Johnny Although, just for fun, I think I'll run some simulations to see how long it would take for that to build up in the tank.

Answer (score 1):

To pressurize water you can simply put a tank on the roof (or build a new water tower) and feed with pumps from storage tanks lower down. This is done in in many high rise buildings in New York were the municipal water pressure is not big enough to reach the higher floors.

If the roof is not strong enough to hold a water tank (and you are not allowed to build another tower) you can instead use a captive-air tank as [mentioned by @Ecnerwal](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/49724/toxicity-problems-with-using-propane-gas-to-pressurize-water#comment69511_49724) to prevent pollution from the driving gas.

Comment: I considered this solution, actually. It's a good idea, but in my case there are reasons it won't work, some of which you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Buy a captive-air (bladder) pressure tank (accumulator) and be done with it. If you pressurize water with nitrogen without a bag/bladder/diaphragm, you're going to discover that nitrogen does dissolve in water. This is a very evolved technology where you are stunningly unlikely to invent something better than what already exists, and certain to spend more money "re-inventing" it than it would cost to buy.